# Resources for learning about transistor configurations?

Tags: operational-amplifier, transistors, analog, integrated-circuit

I'm currently taking a circuits class that discusses various transistor amplifier configurations eventually culminating in building an op-amp. This includes various configurations such as the darlington pair, cascades, or cascode transistors. Are there any good online resources I could check out to help me study that you guys know of? I've been looking for awhile now but all my searches overwhelmingly return results for basic circuits 1 classes, and I can't seem to find what I'm looking for.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: I've found *The Art of Electronics*, Horowitz and Hill, to be a good resource, although they do digress into a number of topics aside from transistor circuits. Bezhad Razavi's electronics book may also be good for you, although copies are a bit expensive (at least in my area).

Comment: Archive.org has all the old books

Comment: For fun, examine the "Levardin" patents, on avoiding bipolar thermal distortion